# What's the easiest way to make this elevated outdoor platform "safe enough" for hunting

Tags: wood, framing, deck

Long story short I bought a house with an existing home made tree stand. I understand these aren't routinely recommended for hunting but I really don't care that much. It's in a good spot and would like to make the best of it. The posts are only buried about 1/2 to 1 foot and theoretically if you rock the entire thing back and forth with enough force you could push it over with some serious manpower. I'm just looking for some advice on how I can make it just safe enough to prevent the floor from falling if the 4 bolts on each corner sheer (if that's even possible for gentle use to sit on) and a way to rig my harness so at least I don't fall all the way to the ground. For the harness either running a line between two trees over top and using that or an eye bolt on the existing 4x4 posts but again that would be relying on the existing hardware. This stand isn't that old in my opinion based on how the posts look and this was built on residential property by the previous owners. All input is appreciated.

[image: One of the photos of the tree stand.]

Photos:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubN2E.jpg

Comment: Those trees aren't strong enough to support a line that would carry your weight, unless you guy them.

Answer (score 3):

Actual X-bracing, not just a few diagonals.

If the ground is amenable, sink 4 posts to reasonable depth and bolt those legs to them. If not, more outriggers or guy wires. Or do both.

Beware the brace to what appears to be a dead rotting tree. Those fall over with some regularity. That might take you along for the ride. *i.e.* remove that brace, brace to something solid.

The two black cherries (or red pines? Bark is similar, can't see  a leaf) appear to be in good health and suitably positioned to attach a line to, preferably by a means that does not ruin their potential future value as lumber or veneer.

Some suitable deck brackets could reduce the concern about bolts shearing by using hardware more suited to the task of holding up a platform to supplement what you have now.

Comment: Those are solid solutions and I appreciate your response. If I were to run a line between the trees would I have to be concerned about how tight that line is? I understand tree houses for example usually float and have a Sliding bracket on one side for the anchor to allow for movement. Thanks

Comment: For "fall protection", do a search on the OSHA website to get specific information. The calculation is quite tedious. Also, from the safety equipment store, they shall be able to provide advice. I suggest adding a horizontal beam in each frame then provide the X-brace above and below.